Count the number of identical values ​in a DataFrame Python
I have a dataframe with two columns: hash and results.
The hash column contains the task ID, it can be repeated several times.
The result column contains the user's answer to this task. The answers contain specific string values ​​like: "Yes", "No", "Perhaps", 404"
My task is to calculate the consistency of user answers.
For example, if 3 users answered the same way to a task with one hash, then the consistency is 100%. If 2 out of 3 answered the same way, then 66.6. If one of 3, then 33.3%. If everyone answered differently, then 0.
I tried to calculate the maximum number of repeated answer values ​​for each hash via "duplicated", but this does not work when there are no repeated values.
Please tell me what functions can be used to solve this problem.
df for example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'hash': list('AAABBBCCCCDDD'),
               'results': ['Yes', 'No', 'No',
                           'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',
                           'Perhaps', 'Yes', '404', 'Perhaps',
                           'Yes', 'No', 'Perhaps',
                          ]
              })


It gives the number of each answer. How to get only the number of answers that occur most often?

Yes, it is precisely the number of these most frequent values for each hash.

My bad, I initially misread the question.

read notice: [mre]

Since you do not provide any reference code, I create a mini python script to simulate your code. This is what I used:
First I create a function that can take the df and make all the operation
def calculate_consistency(df):

Then, first of all, I grouped all the records at the hash, and result columns:
df.groupby('hash')['result'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)


df.groupby('hash') this function creates a GroupBy object where all rows with the same 'hash' value are grouped together.
[result'] This selects only the 'result' column from each group.
We're now working with groups of 'result' values for each unique 'hash'.
.value_counts() This method counts the occurrences of each unique value in the 'result' column
.unstack() This transforms the Series of Series (resulting from value_counts) into a DataFrame. Each unique 'result' value becomes a column. Each 'hash' becomes a row.
fill_value=0: This is an argument to unstack(). It fills any missing values (NaN) with 0.

Then, calculate total responses for each hash
total_responses = grouped.sum(axis=1)

To find the maximum count for each hash
max_counts = grouped.max(axis=1)

And finally, calculate consistency percentage and return the consistency.
consistency = (max_counts / total_responses) * 100
return consistency

The full code, with the example looks like this:
import pandas as pd

def calculate_consistency(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('hash')['result'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
    total_responses = grouped.sum(axis=1)
    max_counts = grouped.max(axis=1)
    consistency = (max_counts / total_responses) * 100
    return consistency


df = pd.DataFrame({'hash': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'result': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Perhaps', '404', 'Yes']})

result = calculate_consistency(df)
print(result)

Let me know if this is useful for you, good luck!

Thank you very much, it works and is very detailed.
There is one thing left, if all the answers are different, it also gives 33%, how in this case can it be done so that it gives 0?

In this case we should take care also the unique_responses, so, after the max_counts variable, we should add a new variable call unique_responses = (grouped > 0).sum(axis=1)  to calculate the number of unique responses for each hash, and finally update the consistency  variable for this new concept consistency = ((max_counts / total_responses) * 100).where(
(unique_responses != total_responses) | (total_responses <= 2), 0)

Don't forget to vote up the useful question, and choose the most aceptable for your case! It was a pleasure

IIUC, you could build a crosstab, get the (first) most common value and compute the consistency:
df = pd.DataFrame({'hash': list('AAABBBCCCCDDD'),
                   'results': ['Yes', 'No', 'No',
                               'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',
                               'Perhaps', 'Yes', '404', 'Perhaps',
                               'Yes', 'No', 'Perhaps',
                              ]
                  })

# compute crosstab
tmp = pd.crosstab(df['hash'], df['results'])

# are all values different?
m = tmp.le(1).all(axis=1)

out = (pd.DataFrame({'top_answer': tmp.idxmax(axis=1).mask(m, '-'),
                     'consistency': tmp.max(axis=1)
                                       .div(tmp.sum(axis=1))
                                       .mask(m, 0)
                    })
         .reset_index()
      )

Output:
  hash top_answer  consistency
0    A         No     0.666667
1    B        Yes     1.000000
2    C    Perhaps     0.500000
3    D          -     0.000000

Another approach with groupby:
df = pd.DataFrame({'hash': list('AAABBBCCCCDDD'),
                   'results': ['Yes', 'No', 'No',
                               'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',
                               'Perhaps', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Perhaps',
                               'Yes', 'No', 'Perhaps',
                              ]
                  })

g = df.groupby('hash')['results']

# number of answers
na = g.size()

# number of unique answers
nu = g.nunique()

# most common answer
mc = g.agg(lambda x: x.mode().str.cat(sep='/'))

# count of most frequent
cnt = g.value_counts().groupby(level='hash').max()

# are all answers different?
m = nu == na

out = (pd.DataFrame({'top_answer': mc.mask(m, '-'),
                     'consistency': (nu/na).mask(m, 0),
                     'nb_answers': na,
                     'nb_unique_answers': nu,
                     'count_top': cnt,
                    })
         .reset_index()
      )

Variant to compute the most common answer:
# count of most frequent
tmp = g.value_counts().reset_index(1)
cnt = tmp.groupby(level=0)['count'].max()

# most common answer
mc = (tmp.loc[tmp['count'].eq(cnt),'results']
         .groupby(level=0).agg('/'.join)
     )

Note that in case of a tie, this will concatenate the most common answers, if you want just one (randomly) use mc = g.agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).
Output:
  hash   top_answer  consistency  nb_answers  nb_unique_answers  count_top
0    A           No     0.666667           3                  2          2
1    B          Yes     0.333333           3                  1          3
2    C  Perhaps/Yes     0.500000           4                  2          2
3    D            -     0.000000           3                  3          1


This works fine too, thank you very much. Only if all the answers are different, I need to get 0, tell me pls how this could be done most rationally

@Dmitry see if the update is what you want, but please edit your question to add a [mre] with the expected output (you can reuse my example if you like)
